# not able to use [index] to access jquery objects

Tags: jquery

In the code below, the var "titles" represents a list of TD objects in a table.  I need to access this list using titles[index] expression and couldn't quite figure out why it is not working for me.

```
var titles = source.children("tbody").children("tr").children("td");
titles.each(function( index ) {
if ($(this) !=null) {
    alert("TD "+index+"="+$(this).html());   //This works fine
    alert("TD "+index+"="+titles[index].html()); // this doesn;t work.
}
```

Comment: Why not using `$(this)`?

Comment: BTW, `if ($(this) !=null)`doesn't make sense!

Comment: I can't use $(this) because the loop is happening on a diff object.  During looping of this other object, I need to get the correponding html in the titles object.  Yes, if ($this) !=null) does not make sense.  I went insane after several failed attempts to access titles without using $(this) :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the array index on a jQuery object, you're actually getting the raw DOM element, so you would need to wrap it in the jQuery wrapper to use the `.html()` method.

```
$(titles[index]).html();
```

The above would work but It would make more sense to use `$(this)` or [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).